# Multiply two matrices with different dimensions in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply, sapply

I am trying to use (s)apply to multiply two matrices with different dimensions. The matrices are:

```
xx <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), nrow=2, ncol=3, byrow=T)
yy <- matrix(c(10, 100), nrow=2, ncol=1, byrow=T)
```

What I want is to multiply each row of one matrix for each row of the other matrix and obtain this:

```
> zz
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]    10    20    30
[2,]   400   500   600
```

I have tried `sapply(yy, function(x) xx*x)` which produces a 6x2 matrix instead of the 3x2 matrix I want. Also `apply(yy, 2, function(x) xx*x)` which produces a 6x1 matrix does not work.
In a similar situation in the past I used `sapply` without problem so I do not understand why this is not working now (I always had a bit of trouble in wrapping my head around `*apply`). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert `yy` to a vector by `c()` and it will be recycled to the dimension of `xx` when multiplying.

```
xx * c(yy)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   10   20   30
# [2,]  400  500  600
```

Or by matrix multiplication :

```
diag(c(yy)) %*% xx
```

Comment: This is the solution that works best for my case, but the other suggestions work too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sweep` :

```
sweep(xx, 1, yy, `*`)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   20   30
#[2,]  400  500  600
```

Or make dimensions of `yy` same as `xx` and directly multiply :

```
xx * yy[row(xx),]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `apply`

```
apply(xx, 2, function(x) x * yy)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   20   30
[2,]  400  500  600
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
xx * yy[,1]
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   20   30
#[2,]  400  500  600
```